# Property does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, api, laravel-eloquent

Pelo que pesquisei pode ser algo relacionado ao fato de ter relacionamento `1:N`, `hasMany` **>** `belongsTo`, porém não sei o que tenho que fazer.

Estou desenvolvendo uma `API` em Laravel 5.5 e tenho umas tabelas que se relacionam quando o relacionamento é `1:1`, traz os resultados normalmente, porém, quando tenho tabelas que o relacionamento é `1:N`, dá a mensagem: `Property does not exist on this collection instance`.

**Informações:**

A tabela de usuários `[login_users]` se relaciona com a tabela de comportamentos `[behaviors]`, `1:N` e na `[behaviors]` só tem o `id`.

E a tabela de comportamento `[behaviors]` se relaciona com a tabela de palavras chave de comportamento `[lkp_key_behaviors]`, `1:1` e na `[lkp_key_behaviors]`, possui as palavras de comportamento como: Liderança, Organização, etc

Quando troco o relacionamento pra `1:1`, `hasOne` **>** `belongsTo` das Models `LoginUser` e `Behavior`, traz os resultados, porém naturalmente não traz todos os comportamentos, traz somente o primeiro.

Model: LoginUser

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Behavior','login_user_id');
}
```

Model: Behavior

```
public function loginuser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LoginUser','login_user_id');
}

public function lkpkeybehavior()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\LkpKeyBehavior','key_behavior_id');
}
```

Model: LkpKeyBehavior

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Behavior','key_behavior_id');
}
```

Controller: LoginUserController

```
public function show($id)
{
    $loginuser = $this->loginuser->find($id);
    $behavior = $loginuser->behaviors->lkpkeybehavior;
    $lkpkeybehavior = $behavior->lkpkeybehavior;
    return response()->json(['User Profile' => $loginuser]);                           
}
```

Comment: Uma pergunta, esse banco é legado (ou seja, já existia) ou é um banco novo? Se for novo você fugiu muito do padrão e não precisa fazer tanta coisa como está fazendo, esses relacionamentos podem ser melhorados.

Comment: É banco novo, posso modificar se necessário. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Seguir as normas que estão descrita no próprio site, um exemplo quando criar as relações sempre é o nome da tabela com `_id` exemplo `cliente_id` e não esse nome grande sem padrão. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Então,que nome grande sem padrão? Porque os nomes das tabelas estão recebendo os _id, no final. As tabelas estão recebendo o nome no plural, como padrão e ficando nesse formato -> Nome da tabela: login_users, chave primária: login_user_id. Nome da tabela: behaviors, chave primária: behavior_id. Nome da tabela: lkp_key_behaviors, chave primária: lkp_key_behavior_id. Ao meu ver isso é um padrão, e está de acordo com a documentação laravel. Era sua sugestão?!